# What is this airport outside of Cairo, Egypt?

Tags: airport-identification

Out to the east of Cairo, Egypt, is a large two-runway airport that Google Maps calls "Capital Cairo Airport" or "Capital International Airport". [Here's a link.](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Capital+Cairo+Airport/@30.0741057,31.8340216,5927m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x19a7b408cfdf4b7e!8m2!3d30.0754632!4d31.8453956) However, I can't find any information about this airport or what it's used for. Cairo has a major international airport within the city, [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cairo+International+Airport/@30.1147007,31.4019488,8404m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xe065af2151e21386!8m2!3d30.1116471!4d31.3985825), so I'm confused as to what this large airport only 30-40 minutes away is.

As far as I can tell, it doesn't appear on Wikipedia's [List of airports in Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Egypt), and satellite view shows no planes parked at this airport. Satellite view history in Google Earth shows that two years ago, the airport only had one runway, but since then the second runway was added. So apparently this airport was important enough to merit two runways, both over 10,000 ft. Why? What is it used for? Does anyone know?

[image]

30°02'52.55" N  31°49'55.05" E

Comment: The geotagged photos Google supplies seem to indicate this might, maybe also be called "Katameya Airport." A search on that is very sparse on English-language details (or I'd post this as an answer), but does seem to indicate a dual-use military/civilian airport here, under construction. It's unclear exactly what the current status of the project is, to the extent I can't be positive we're talking about the same place, but a few sources (e.g. [this one](http://wikimapia.org/3711047/Katameya-International-Airport)) indicate as such.

Comment: It's apparently identical to [another new airport](http://www.skyscrapercity.com/showthread.php?t=1956418). Seems like it's good to be in the airport construction business in Egypt!

Comment: [Katameya International Airport](http://www.avit.com.eg/index.php/projects/item/138-katameya-airport), ex-military.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The two runways to the east form an existing air force base called [Wadi Al Jandali AFB](http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/world/egypt/airfield.htm). The new western runway and terminal form a new civilian airport called **Katameya/Al-Qatameya Airport.** It is also known as **Capital International Airport.**

[image]
([Source](http://www.ahram.org.eg/Media/News/2016/10/27/2016-636131992635642734-564.jpg))

The airport is set to serve a [new administrative capital](http://english.ahram.org.eg/NewsContentP/1/278593/Egypt/UPDATED-Egypts-Sisi-launches-new-capital-project-.aspx) that is yet to be completed.

Another new airport, [Sphinx Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giza_Sphinx_International_Airport), is west of Cairo. It is [also adjacent to an existing AFB](http://english.ahram.org.eg/NewsContent/1/64/130476/Egypt/Politics-/Egypt-to-open-two-military-airports-for-civil-flig.aspx) called Cairo West.

> Al-Qatameya will serve the new administrative capital project and the Cairo West airport will receive charter flights, along with Cairo International Airport to ease pressure.

They are not operational in the sense of scheduled air traffic. Google Earth shows what can only be the new Sphinx Airport (west of Cairo West AFB):

[image]
30°06'15.42" N  30°54'03.38" E